# How to sum series of this form

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking at sums of this form:

$1+2(a+b+c)+3(ab+bc+ca)+4abc$.

Is there a way compute them in a nicer form?

Formally, given a set $A=\{a,b,c,\ldots\}$ made by $N$ distinct numbers, I want to compute:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N}(i+1)\sum_{\substack{B\subseteq A\\ |B|=i}}\prod_{b\in B}b. $$

Comment: It is an interesting question, but your last lines are not very clear, so I suggest you to improve the terminology. Have a look at my answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks !! It's actually not exactly this sum,but it can be decomposed partially to this, so I had trouble deciding exactly what to ask. I was thinking something along polynomial sum, so your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we want to compute in a nicer form:
$$ S_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}(i+1)\cdot e_i(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \tag{1}$$
where $e_i$ is an [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). It is well-known that:
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+t\cdot a_j) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} t^i e_i(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\tag{2} $$
hence it follows that:
$$ S_n = \left. \frac{d}{dt}\left(t\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+t\cdot a_j)\right)\right|_{t=1} \tag{3}$$
and by the chain rule, assuming that $a_i\neq -1$ for every $i\in[1,n]$:

> $$ S_n = \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{a_j}{a_j+1}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+a_j).\tag{4}$$